# Caffeine Cache with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, caffeine, caffeine-cache

I have my DAO layers with an expensive method as followed:

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"userStories"})
public class UserStoryDaoImpl implements IUserStoryDao {

@Override
@Cacheable
public List<UserStory> getUserStoriesForProjectAndRelease(UserDto userDto, Set<Integer> 
reportProjectId, int releaseId) {
    //Slow performing business logic that returns a list
    return new ArrayList(); 
}
```

and another as

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"features"})
public class FeatureDaoImpl implements IFeatureDao {

@Override
@Cacheable
public List<Features> geFeaturesForProjectAndRelease(UserDto userDto, Set<Integer> reportProjectId, 
int releaseId) {
    //Slow performing business logic that returns a list
    return new ArrayList();
 }
}
```

and my cache config class as :

```
@Configuration
public class CaffeineCacheConfig {

 @Bean
 public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager("features", "userStories");
    cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder());
    return cacheManager;
 }

 Caffeine< Object, Object > caffeineCacheBuilder() {
    return Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .initialCapacity(100)
            .maximumSize(500)
            .expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .refreshAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .weakKeys()
            .recordStats();
 }
}
```

I am using spring boot :: 2.2.6.RELEASE and my pom include :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something in this? I want to maintain a cache "features" &"userStories" and update it asynchronously after call to the DAO method is made.

I am getting following error :

Cannot load configuration class: com.packageName.CaffeineCacheConfig

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine

I have found these reports related to a similar issue: [CaffeineGit-1](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/1536) and [CaffeineGit-Related](https://github.com/google/error-prone/pull/1398)